# Map API v2 Authorisation Failure

Tags: android, android-maps, google-maps-api-2

Alright, here is what I did using the [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

1. Got the debug key via keytool (made sure it is the the debug key is used by eclipse in Preferences -> Android -> Build)
2. Generated the key by the command

   $ keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
3. Copy pasted the SHA1 sum in the Google API Console + my packagename:

   sum;com.my.package
4. Enabled Google Map API v2 in the same project in Google API Console
5. Copied  it to the Manifest application in meta-data.
6. Downloaded via SDK manager and Imported the google-play-services_lib project and referenced it as the library project. As well as the ActionBarSherlock.
7. Before launching I make sure the GooglePlayServices are available.

Manifest:

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<permission
    android:name="com.my.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.my.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Application:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="debug_key"/>
```

The proguard stuff are added too, but I don't obfuscate right now.

DrugstoresMapActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

project.properties

```
target=android-17
android.library.reference.1=../google-play-services_lib
android.library.reference.2=../ActionBarSherlock
```

The ActionBarSherlock has android-support-v4 in libs, not the main project if that matters.

The StartupActivity makes sure that DrugstoresMapActivity will be launched only if the services available

```
private void attempt() {
    int result = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    switch (result) {
        case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, DrugstoresMapActivity.class));
            finish();
            break;

        default:
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result, this, REQUEST_DIALOG)
                .show();
            break;
    }
}
```

Double-checked the keys are fine.
No clue what I missed here.

Comment: just curious, how did you find out about this? I'm on tech blogs everyday, and on the android developer documents everyday, and I only happened to find out about this from trying to solve an impossible problem with android maps v1 in my existing code.

Comment: Find out about what. About Wrong service enabled? If yes, you should have asked that in the answer comment, not the question to make it clearer. I found the suggestion somewhere in StackOverflow here after hours browsing different problems regarding this issue.

Comment: no, how did you find out about android maps v2, I realize I'm *only* two weeks late, but I think its kind of a big deal

Comment: I was looking for docs (API Reference) in google.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Wrong service was enabled.
Make sure the "Google Maps Android API v2", not "Google Maps API v2" is enabled and re-generate the API key.

Comment: +1 Bingo.. :) I stucked with the API key, deleting keystores, rename app package..

Comment: After enabling Google Maps Android API v2 it was still not working for me. So I tried changing the target sdk in my manifest to 17 from 16 and that fixed it. Note switching back to 16 also still worked.

Comment: Oh my word - this was my problem as well and I was pulling my hair out.  Thank you!!

Comment: THANK YOU A MILLION! I was stuck on this issue for 2 days!

Comment: Bazinga!!! Damn! I can't thank you more!! I will cross share your answer with others. I am sure they will appreciate it!  :-D :-D

Comment: +1000000000 for you! I'm taking you out to wherever you want to go. I've been stuck on this issue for days and I didn't realize there was a separate maps service for Android.

Comment: if you come from API v1 with the same app packages names, it does not work with debug key, you need to change the package name.