# Error in Google Maps android "android Failed to load map. Could not contact Google servers."

Tags: android, google-maps

i am trying to implement google maps in my android application but i am stuck on an error 
"`android Failed to load map. Could not contact Google servers`."
i have included google play library, got the key using SHA1 certificate fingerprint.
i got the SHA1 certificate fingerprint as :

```
 sudo keytool -v -list -alias androiddebugkey \-keystore /home/.android/debug.keystore
```

i managed my manifest file according to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598596/google-maps-api-v2-failed-to-load-map-could-not-contact-google-servers-even)

now i am unable to find the cause of this error.. any suggestion is greatly appreciated...

- i have seen questions on stackoverflow but didnt got any solution!

**EDIT**:
my manifest file permissions are as:

```
<permission
    android:name="PAKG_NAME.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="PAKG_NAME.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />


<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />


.....................

      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY_KEY" />
```

and my layout xml have fragment as:

```
  <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Logcat output:

```
 E/Google Maps Android API(31478): Failed to load map.  Could not contact Google servers.
```

Comment: i changed/recreated api key sevral times but getting the same error

Comment: @Saad Khokhar-post your xml here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you have enabled "Google Maps Android API v2" and not "Google Maps API v2"?
After changing that, delete and recreate the API key. This worked for me...

Comment: Can't believe it: made that exact misstake. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Try right click on your project and select Properties > Android > and in "Project Build target" select Google APIs. That worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure about your API key, you should uninstall program from your phone and install again. It worked for me :)

Comment: I think that android store first used API key in program cache so you need to clear the cache or uninstall application for using the new API key

Answer (score 0):

Have u enable Google android map API v2 in console check
 It properly .
I think u enable Google map v2 that why request failed...

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api. I think u create API project in Google console.

Comment: i have enabled Google Maps Android API v2 from console but still getting the same error

Comment: @gupta, yes i have followed all those steps

Comment: @Saad Khokhar-please post your logcat output.

Comment: please look into question, i have edited it with my logcat output!

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you have duplicate API_KEY for the same project. As you know, we will use sha1 key and android project name for getting an API key. If you try to use same sha1;android_project_name pair to get API key, Google will give you another API key. So its duplicated. If you delete the newer one and use the older one in your project, it will solve your problem. 
At least I hope :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when refactoring and changing my project bundle identifier. If is this your case, you will have to create a new project on Google Developer Console and link again to your project. For some reason Google blocks requests from the same app if it changes its ID.