# Java android Google map doesn't show map (white screen)

Tags: android, google-maps

I see only white screen when I start Activity I did  this :

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    public static final String DISPLAY_MARKERS_LIMIT = "map_activity_display_markers_limit";

    public static final int MARKERS_LIMIT = 1000;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(37.4233438, -122.0728817))
                .title("LinkedIn")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(37.4629101,-122.2449094))
                .title("Facebook")
                .snippet("Facebook HQ: Menlo Park"));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(37.3092293, -122.1136845))
                .title("Apple"));

        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(37.4233438, -122.0728817), 10));

    }
}
```

in logis I see

```
10-25 11:01:52.090 13971-13971/pl.. W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
10-25 11:01:53.030 13971-13971/pl.. D/AbsListView: viewType is heaer or footer
10-25 11:01:53.040 13971-13971/pl.. D/AbsListView: viewType is heaer or footer
10-25 11:01:53.100 13971-13971/pl. W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
10-25 11:01:53.580 13971-15476/pl. I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
10-25 11:01:53.580 13971-15476/pl. I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
10-25 11:01:53.610 13971-15476/pl. I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 38 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 13971, getuid(): 10720
10-25 11:01:53.640 13971-15476/pl. I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 38
```

And this is my layout

```
<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

And this is content_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".activities.MapActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main ::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activities.MapActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you adding this  `tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"` so please post  your code of `activity_main`

Comment: @GowthamanM I added

Comment: @GowthamanM now I see this:  E/Google Maps Android API: Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

Comment: ok then you need to just change the api key in the manifest file...

Comment: @GowthamanM But this api works when I created new project

Comment: ok then do one thing....uninstall your app..clean and rebuild your project..install it again..let me know

Comment: just take look at this kind of similar problem..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667935/failed-to-load-map-error-contacting-google-servers-this-is-probably-an-authent

Comment: @GowthamanM I did this and it doesn't work

Comment: @jpok2 are you sure that this is the error. please check verbose or Error log once again

Comment: @JinsLukose in logs i see : /Google Maps Android API: Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

Comment: @jpok2 did you added SHA- 1 key to developer console?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166214/error-in-google-maps-android-android-failed-to-load-map-could-not-contact-goog check this once

Comment: @JinsLukose yes I added when I create a new project It works good

Comment: @jpok2 can you please add your manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

I think it caused bay not having api-key of google maps. if you have not added SHA-1 to key than add new SHA-1 certificate fingerprint to maps.
you may find helpful below link
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup