# Fix the Failed to load map. Could not contact Google servers.

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using the map functionality in my app.Whenever I run map in my app I got error i.e.

`04-19 11:03:50.274: E/Google Maps Android API(23366): Failed to load map.  Could not contact Google servers.`

I have checked manifest file and code  all is correct.And Google play service is also working in my android device. I am running sample code of map same error I have got.But I am not understanding what is exact problem.Please suggest me how to fix that problem. 
`

Comment: check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598596/google-maps-api-v2-failed-to-load-map-could-not-contact-google-servers-even
hope helped..

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727992/google-maps-api-v2-failed-to-load-map-could-not-contact-google-servers  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497179/google-maps-android-api-v2-failed-to-load-map-could-not-contact-google-servers

Answer (score 2):

Have you adquire your map-key in [Google Api Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) using the package name of your project and your SH1 of the Keytore?
If not, go to console and do it ;)
You have to put this key in your Manifest, and the permissions required.

Normally this error happens when:

- No valid map-key.
- The key is not for your keystore.
- You forgot some permision.

===============Mini tutorial=====================

1. Download and install Google Play Services from SDKManager
2. Go to [Google Api Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console)
3. On your left, Create new Project (Give the name you want)
4. Know in the "services" option is allowed, so go inside the option.
5. Turn On Google Maps Android API v2
6. Know in click on "Generate new Android Key" in the page showed
7. You will need your SHA1  from the  Keystore and the name of the project package
   `Ex: 48:+4: ... :46;com.xxxx.xxx.xxx`
8. To know your sha1 you have to open a CMD and do:

   ```
   C:\>cd C:\Users\YOURUSER\.android\

   C:\Users\YOURUSER\.android>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdkXXXX\bin\keytool.exe" -list -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
   ```

   XXX Means the version you have
9. Now you got your api key go to your Manifest have to put:

   ...
       
   ...
10. Select the project, right click, go to "File/Import/Android/Existing Android Code into Workspace". In the root directory go to `"<-sdk-android folder> /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib"`
    and select the project that appears. Click Finish.
11. Right click on project go to "Properties/Android"; click on "Add.." button, and choose google play services and click on OK
12. Add `android-support-v4.jar` to your project if isn't yet.
13. THe layout of the map is:
14. And the activity that contains the map has to extend FragmentActivity (Something like this)

    `public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
        {`

    ```
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       }    
    ...
    }
    ```
15. AAAAND thats all!

Answer (score 0):

Have you generated an api key for your app, using your keystore and package name?

Comment: Thanks, I have resolved this problem.I am using wrong signed Google API key in my app.Please remember that this error come when we are using wrong Google API key in manifest file.