# Authorization failure at different devices (Android Google Map API v2)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I succeeded in running google map in my app on the tablet(ASUS TF201). However, it can't work on my other Android mobile phones(Samsung, HTC...).

I use SHA1 generated by keytool, register on google api console, and get the debug key. Import lib and set permission step by step.

Console appears this wherever I run it:

```
[2013-03-28 11:19:18 - google-play-services_lib] Could not find google-play-services_lib.apk!
```

Appear on the tablet which works well,too.

Failure if it's with below logcat:

```
 03-28 11:10:56.382: E/Google Maps Android API(32067): Failed to load map.  Could not contact Google servers.
    03-28 11:03:54.165: E/Google Maps Android API(9610): Authorization failure.
    03-28 11:03:55.135: D/dalvikvm(9610): GC_CONCURRENT freed 286K, 13% free 10643K/12231K, paused 24ms+3ms, total 89ms
    03-28 11:03:55.580: E/Google Maps Android API(9610): Failed to load map.  Could not contact Google servers.
    03-28 11:03:55.595: E/Google Maps Android API(9610): Failed to load map.  Could not contact Google servers.
    03-28 11:03:56.085: E/Google Maps Android API(9610): Failed to load map.  Could not contact Google servers.
    ...
```

I can't find which steps I missed. Please give me some suggestion if you knew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this problem by myself!

At [Google console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) > `API ACess` > `Edit allowed Android apps...`

`SHA1 Key; Android app packet name`

The packet name need to be set to the **leaf** of the structure. For example, `com.peter.example1` works but `com.peter` is invalid. Though I still don't know why it works on the tablet with wrong setting.

Answer (score 0):

```
Could not find google-play-services_lib.apk!
```

The Map API v2 uses google services whick may not be available on all devices. You should check if it exists explicitly as described here

[Google Play Services | Setup](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)

```
Authorization failure
```

Maybe you did not export apk with production key? If you install by pressing run on Eclipse it uses debug key, if you choose to export signed apk you can use a different key.

All setup I did you can find here and see if you missed something

[Map API v2 Authorisation Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803833/map-api-v2-authorisation-failure/13805807#13805807)

Comment: 1. I query for `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()` method to check the state, but two of my device return `0` which means ` SUCCESS` in the document. I still can't solve this problem with my phone.
2. So far, I only run it by connecting the USB cable, not APK.